# How can I capture the closed timestamp of an AWS Account using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Using `list_accounts` boto3 I was able to get the Joined Timestamp, however this time I want to capture the closed timestamp of all accounts in my AWS Organization that are in closed status. Can someone tell me if there is a Boto3 function available to fetch this data ? TIA

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If an account is closed or not has nothing to do with the organization and their for you cant use boto3(oragnization) to get the info like joined timestamp with the list_accounts. With the list_accounts you just see the the time stamp you joined (this is info related to organization) you can not see the timestamp of when the account was created (this info is related to the account).

Comment: I got your point, but is there a way I can get the timestamp when account was closed using boto3 ?

Comment: If it was possible it should be under account in boto3:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.18.52/reference/services/account.html#id3
But it is not so I would be confident to say no it is not possible.